# How to run Angular 2 with hot module replacement?

Tags: angular, webpack, hot-module-replacement

I do according to the instruction: [instruction](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/angular2-hmr)

HMR does not work - the page is rebooted entirely.

What could go wrong? Please ask clarifying questions

Comment: I am searching for answer on this. Were you able to do it ?